# Django page not found error

Tags: django

Hello I am trying to solve the error which keeps on occurring;

my current code on mysite/urls.py is

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from polls import views

admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = [
                   url(r'^polls/$', views.index, name='index'),
                   url(r'^polls/(?P<question_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
                   url(r'^polls/(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
                   url(r'^polls/(?P<question_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
                   url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                   ]
```

and I am getting error when I try to access :8001/polls

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls,
Django tried these URL  patterns, in this order:
    ^polls/$ [name='index']
    ^polls/(?P<question_id>\d+)/$ [name='detail']
    ^polls/(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$ [name='vote']
    ^polls/(?P<question_id>\d+)/results/$ [name='results']
    admin/
The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

Please help me to solve this error which makes me cannot access to the website.

Comment: Try to append  this `url(r'^/$', views.index, name='index')` at the end of the `urlpatterns` list

Comment: The error should be clear: you have not defined a URL for the root path.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? What view would you like to access at the root of your site?

Comment: I guess `:8001/polls` is not root. Maybe `:8001/`  is root ? Maybe issue is missing `/` at the end of url try `:8001/polls/`